# socket.io returning data, but React useEffect is not setting users state

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, socket.io

I have a component that creates a socket event newUserResponse, and when I console.log('CLIENT newUserResponse data', data) I can see data printed out in the console.
However when console.log('CLIENT Updated users', users); runs I don't see any data in console,
and the users.map does not render anything on the page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./Chat.css"

const ChatBar = ({ socket }) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("newUserResponse", (data) => {
            console.log('CLIENT newUserResponse data', data); // Log received data
            setUsers((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, ...data]);
            console.log('CLIENT Updated users', users);
        })
    }, [socket, users])
    return (
        <div className='chat__sidebar'>
            <h2>Open Chat</h2>
            <div>
                <h4 className='chat__header'>ACTIVE USERS</h4>
                <div className='chat__users'>
                    {users.map((user) => <p key={user.socketID}>{user.userName}</p>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChatBar;
```

I am expecting {users.map((user) => {user.userName}

)} showing the names of the users connected to the chat